# Kendo Map: How to select all shapes when dataSource is a Multipolygon?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, geojson, kendo-dataviz

I have a Kendo Dataviz UI Map that is displaying all 50 US states, and I need the states to be selectable and change colors when selected.  This is easy enough, it looks something like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Map()
      .Name("myMap")
      .Layers(layers =>
      {
          layers.Add()
              .Type(MapLayerType.Shape)
              .DataSource(dataSource =>
              {
                  dataSource.GeoJson();                      
                  dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("GetShapes", "MyController");
              });              
      })
      .Events(events => events
          .ShapeClick("onShapeClick")
      )
)

...

function onShapeClick(e) {
    var newColor = "#ff0000";
    e.shape.fill(newColor);

    //var shapeUid = e.shape.dataItem.uid;
    //TODO:  get a list of all shapes on the map
    //Call shape.fill on any other shapes that share the same uid
}
```

The code works for most states.  It doesn't work right when the geoJSON source is of type "Multipolygon", as it is with AK, HI, VA, MI, and a few others.  Shape.fill() only colors in the polygon that was clicked, not the entire state.  So for example, if you click on one of Hawaii's islands, the other three islands don't get filled in.

There's a uid for each shape corresponding to the shape's dataitem, and these are the same for different shapes in the same state.  But I can't figure out how to find a list of shapes so that I can set the fill on the other shapes?  Or I can't figure out if there is another workaround?  The best I have so far is to convert my geoJSON to only use Polygons, but that's time consuming and also makes the map look uglier.  I haven't been able to find a open source geoJson file that only uses polygons.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry but I'm having the same problem, have you found a solution yet?